# Deployment ID in URL changes when app script runs causing the script to fail, how can I make the URL use the correct Deployment ID?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a script to create an annual leave request workflow that begins with a google form, collects responses in a sheet, then emails a manager for approval, then emails the requester with either an Approved/Denied confirmation email. The script runs and sends the email to the manager, but once either the approve or deny button is pressed, the URL generated uses a deployment ID that does not match the version of either the current /exec
or the /dev version.

Here is the code snippet for the section that should run when the buttons are used:

```
function SheetHandler(sheet) {
  var _sheet = sheet;
  var _data = getRowsData(_sheet);
  
  var _markPending = function(d) {
    
    d.state = PENDING_STATE;
    d.identifier = Utils.generateUUID();
    
    manager_email = d[SETTINGS.MANAGERS_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME].match(EMAIL_REGEX);
    
    var scriptUri = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
    // hack some values on to the data just for email templates.
    d.approval_url = scriptUri + "?i=" + d.identifier + '&state=' + APPROVED_STATE;
    d.deny_url = scriptUri + "?i=" + d.identifier + '&state=' + DENIED_STATE;
    d.manager_email = manager_email

    message = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.PENDING_MANAGER_EMAIL, d);
    subject = Utils.processTemplate(SETTINGS.PENDING_MANAGER_EMAIL_SUBJECT, d);
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(manager_email,subject,"",{ htmlBody: message });
    
    setRowData(_sheet, d);
  }
```

Is there another way to get the correct deployment url for this?

I've tested it by copying the Head and Version deployment ID into the URL generated by the approve/deny buttons in the emails, if I copy the correct ID from the Deploy menu into the URL in place of the incorrect one then the remaining code executes as expected.

The link looks like this:
https://script.google.com/a/macros//s//exec?i=6b843ea2-7b2b-454a-ff2e-89bc9a54d48e&state=APPROVED

Comment: Use Manage Deployments and just edit the old one rather than creating a new one.

Comment: Thats not the problem. I'm not creating new versions or new ones.

The problem is the  deployment ID that is shown in the URL when the script runs doesn't match the deployment ID.

This is the URL including the deployment ID:
https://script.google.com/a/macros/domain/s/AKfycby7n7CCRopY_C59HyB1q8_ElTlsseFQOjGG23_vpm0cTXF9qo5I/exec?i=6b843ea2-7b2b-454a-ff2e-89bc9a54d48e&state=APPROVED

But this is the actual version deployment ID taken from the deployment menu:
AKfycbyk8zzeAVCe0h4jq-6BBM4ttS8IQVLKaQnoEoiqQ0N6Y7WJr8GlaUPVFvgQ7TQ2K8-6

Comment: I thought that your situation might be related to [this issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235862472). In this case, how about using the hard-copied Web Apps URL? And also, when you modified the script, please reflect the latest script in the current version. But, if this was not your expected direction, I apologize.